# Search in multidimensional arrays but stop on the third array

Tags: php, search, multidimensional-array

I would like to search a multidimensional and get the path of the value I'm searching
But only down 2 sub arrays, ignore any sub array if exist.

My test array is:

```
Array
(
    [totalCount] => 3
    [results] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [serialNumber] => DX3Sxxxxxxxx
                    [description] => Device DX3S
                    [location] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 5
                            [locationName] => US
                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 4
                    [serialNumber] => DMPTxxxxxxxx
                    [description] => Device DMPT
                    [syncState] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 7
                            [serialNumber] => DMPTxxxxxxxx
                            [timestamp] => 1614460339303
                        )

                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 5
                    [serialNumber] => C02Xxxxxxxxx
                    [description] => Device C02X
                )

        )

)
```

I found this function witch works amazingly but loops through all the arrays and once found the first value returns the path.

```
// Function to recursively search for a given value
function array_search_id($search_value, $array, $id_path) {
      
    if(is_array($array) && count($array) > 0) {
          
        foreach($array as $key => $value) {
  
            $temp_path = $id_path;
              
            // Adding current key to search path
            array_push($temp_path, $key);
  
            // Check if this value is an array
            // with atleast one element
            if(is_array($value) && count($value) > 0) {
                $res_path = array_search_id(
                        $search_value, $value, $temp_path);
  
                if ($res_path != null) {
                    return $res_path;
                }
            }
            else if("$value" == $search_value) {
                return join(" --> ", $temp_path);
            }
        }
    }
      
    return null;
}
```

For example I need to get the path in the array for the Device ID: 5

and I would like to get: $ --> results --> 2 --> id

```
$search_path = array_search_id("5", $device_array, array('$'));
echo($search_path);
```

but instead I'm getting: $ --> results --> 0 --> location --> id

is there a way to stop the search on the [results] => Array and not looking further down to [location] => Array with the function I found

or do I need a different approach to loop through the arrays?

Thank you in advance

Comment: You should post the expected output

Comment: Hi B001 thank you for replying, as I mentioned in the post I would like to get: $ --> results --> 2 --> id . As the device ID 5 I’m searching is on the device array results[2]